# Tuning a WebService

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, performance

I have a webservice created with CXF. In my service I run an application witch is very time consuming.

My application takes about 30 minutes to be executed but inside the webservice it takes about 1 1/2 hours.

Is there something I can do that my service gets faster?

Comment: it totally depends on what you do in your WebMethod

Comment: just calling my java application as I call it from junit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any good reason for such a difference (assuming your doing the same work). You are going to have to work out what is different about enviroment or the input parameters you are using.

Try turning on `-Xverbose:gc` it may be that you have just about maxed out the heap on the servlet container and the JVM is speading it's whole life running the garabage collector over and over again.

Note you can also see using `jvisualvm` which comes with the JDK for free.

Comment: I was thinking that CXF or Tomcat is doing something after a certain time (e.g. some clean up task).

Comment: not for an hour of CPU time... tomcat is actually a very thin bit of software CXF is no doubt a beast...but still, an hour!

Comment: Sorry just seen your comment about memory, ignore my last edit..it isn't going to be memory (well shouldn't be)

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at the application with jvisualvm in the Sun JDK.

My guess is that you have too little memory in your web service container, and that all the time is spent garbage collecting.

Comment: Yes, I need a lot of memory, I need to start Tomcat with -Xmx1600m. Can I assign memory for the container itself?

Comment: Unfortunately there is a limit of heap size for a windows 32 bit machine: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/tools/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.igaa/_1vg00014884d287-11c3fb28dae-7ff6_1001.html

Comment: @myboro, yes, Windows do not provide more than that.  If you use an IBM JVM, use the equivalent tool to jvisualvm to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't enough information here to solve the issue, you need to figure out what is going on use some sort of tracing/profiling mechanism. It could be a memory issue. I don't know how you're actually launching the app, but it could be that its getting assigned a very low priority thread, vs a more user (high) priority thread when being launched by JUnit. The webservice itself would long time out before half an hour passed, let alone 1.5 hours, so are you using an ASync service or launching your own thread and/or process from the service? If its a separate process, how much memory is being allocated to that?

Once you've gathered this information, you're probably well on your way to really getting your answer.

YMMV

Comment: It's all in the same thread. I included the application project to the webservice project in eclipse.